# Substituting values in a CSV file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm running a couple of simulations for a number of case studies and the results are stored in a csv file in this

```
/   Var1  Var2 Var3
0    x      x    x
1    x      x    x
2    x      x    x
3    x      x    x
0    x      x    x
1    x      x    x
2    x      x    x
```

What i'm trying to do is substitute the first column (which is the index for the simulation numbar for each case) with the case name. What I want to do is for the csv to read like this:

```
/       Var1  Var2 Var3
Case1    x      x    x
Case1    x      x    x
Case1    x      x    x
Case1    x      x    x
Case2    x      x    x
Case2    x      x    x
Case2    x      x    x
```

I've thought of adding a condition where if the number in the first column is 0 the substitute it with case, when the next 0 is found then continue with case+1 (i've got the case names in a vector)

My issue is that I don't know how to access the values in the first row and evaluate them, and subsequently substitute them. I'd imagine pandas must have a convenient way of doing something like this

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best way to do this, but I do know how to do the inverse, if that helps: `df.groupby(index).cumcount()`.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html

Comment: `df.iloc[2, 0]` will for example access the first element of the third line if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or by first column do you mean the index column?

Comment: @Silveris The index column, so that 0,1,2 all become Case1 and then the next 0,1,2,3 become Case2 and so on

Comment: What you can do is get that column as a list using `new_index = df.index.values`, change whatever you want in this list, and then replace the old index column like this: `df.index = new_index`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `groupby`, `cumcount`, and `set_index`:

```
df.set_index('Case'+df.groupby(df.index).cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
```

Output:

```
      Var1 Var2 Var3
Case1    x    x    x
Case1    x    x    x
Case1    x    x    x
Case1    x    x    x
Case2    x    x    x
Case2    x    x    x
Case2    x    x    x
```